# Adding custom role to user ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

**Context of problem**

In my web application I've been using ASP.NET Identity. I've created custom user profiles by inheriting the User class from IdentityUser. To be able to connect the Roles with for example rolegroups I've also created a custom role class within my database which inherits from the IdentityRole class.

*My database model looks like this:* [image: Part of databasemodel]

The problem isn't in creating a user. *This just works:*

```
var userManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(_context));
var result = userManager.Create(user, password);
```

Same with creating a role.

```
var rm = new RoleManager<Role>(new RoleStore<Role>(_context));
var result = rm.Create(new Role(name));
```

**Problem**

But its when I try to attach a role to a user (*With the following code*)

```
var um = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(_context));
var result = um.AddToRole(userId, roleName);
```

The error I get is basically "**The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context.**"

Which is true, btw. But how can I make it that my Role entity is seen as the IdentityRole entity, which it basically is, or has to be.

See the full stacktrace here: http://pastebin.com/sEPv5LiT

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you have two different contexts?  If not using the same context for UserManager and your entities may work:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22672165/433234

Comment: I have a single DbContext. Also, these three pieces of code use the same instance of my DbContext, which shouldn't give any problems AFAIK.

Comment: having the same issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam In the end I 'manually' connect roles to a specific user after the account is created, which works quite well. With manually I just mean editing the database directly without additional layer (in this case the UserManager). I have some sample code for you if you wish.

Comment: @CorstianBoerman maybe its the UserStore thing that worked with me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116426/addtorole-and-identityrole-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to define custom roles for users i prefer to add library project in your solution and manage all membership and roles through this.

[Custom Asp.Net Membership](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers)

I make library project for that if you want i will provide you

Comment: I've already written logic to create custom roles and so on. The only problem right now is that I need to attach these roles to the users of my application. I can't do this by using Entity Framework because I don't have entities of the roles, or wait, what, do I? I'm just thinking that probably the best way to achieve what I want is to manually connect these two entities with entitiy framework. I'm going to try it. :)

Comment: Yes you should do make role and userrole seperate entities

Comment: Off course! Each user is attached to a company on which also roles and rolegroups can be defined. (Not showed in model) The user automatically inherits these roles.