# The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context after extending Roles table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have extended my AspNetRoles that was created by Entity Framework to look like this:

```
public class AspNetRoles:IdentityRole
{
        public AspNetRoles() : base() { }
        public String Label { get; set; }
        public String ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public AspNetApplications Application { get; set; }

        public static readonly String SystemAdministrator = "SystemAdministrator";
}
```

I understood that because I have extended the identityrole table, I had to make changes to my usermanager. This is what I have done:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}

// Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}

public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<AspNetRoles>, IDisposable
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(RoleStore<AspNetRoles> store) : base(store)
    { }


    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        //AppIdentityDbContext db = context.Get<AppIdentityDbContext>();
        //AppRoleManager manager = new AppRoleManager(new RoleStore<AppRole>(db));
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<AspNetRoles>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

        //return manager;
    }
}

public class ApplicationUserStore<TUser> : UserStore<TUser, AspNetRoles, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IUserStore<TUser>, IUserStore<TUser, string>, IDisposable where TUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(DbContext context) : base(context) { }
}
```

This is my DBContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, AspNetRoles, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
    {
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsersExtendedDetails> AspNetUsersExtendedDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetApplications> AspNetApplications { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetEventLogs> AspNetEventLogs { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext() : base("AppStudio")
        {

        }
        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

However, I get this error when I start my application:

The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context.

I'm not sure why this is happening. Have I missed something that needs to be changed after extending my roles table?

Comment: Not sure if you're using Code First or Database First, but customizing roles so far requires modification of `UserStore` and/or `UserManager` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796804/why-am-i-getting-an-identityrole-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116426/addtorole-and-identityrole-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context) for further explanation).

Comment: Hi @TetsuyaYamamoto, I'm using Code First. I have updated my question with some changes I made. Can you check if I'm missing something?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I tried to follow your examples but no change.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Short answer**

The main problem in above code is in `Create` method of `UserManager`. In that method, you should create a `UserManager` using a `UserStore` which is aware of the new role class which you created. To do so, you can use an instance of `ApplicationUserStore` class which you have or create a new user store this way:

```
new UserStore<ApplicationUser, [YourRoleClass], string, 
    IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim(
        context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>())
```

### How to Add a custom Property to IdentityRole?

To add a new property to `IdentityRole`, you can follow the following steps:

1. Create an *ASP.NET Web Application*
2. Make sure you select *MVC* and the *Authentication* is *Individual User Accounts*
3. Go to *Models* folder → Open *IdentityModels.cs* and Create *ApplicationRole* class containing the custom property that you want to add:

   ```
   public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole   //My custom role class
   {
       public string ApplicationId { get; set; } //My custom property
   }
   ```
4. Change `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method of `ApplicationUser` to accept parameter of type of `UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>`:

   ```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
   {
       public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> manager)
       {
   ```
5. Change `ApplicationDbContext` base class and introduce all the generic parameters:

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext()
           : base("DefaultConnection")
       {
   ```
6. Build the project.
7. Go to *TOOLS* menu → *Nuget Package Manager* → click *Package Manager Console*
8. Type `Enable-Migrations` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and wait until the task get completed.
9. Type `Add-Migration "ApplicationRole"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and wait until the task get completed.
10. Type `Update-Database` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and wait until the task get completed.
11. Go to *App_Start* folder → Open *IdentityConfig.cs* and Change the `ApplicationUserManager` class to derive from  `UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>` and also change its `Create` method to return a `UserManage` aware of `ApplicationRole`:

    ```
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, string> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    ```
12. To manage roles, create `ApplicationRoleManager` class in the same file:

    ```
    public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string> store) : base(store) { }

        public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(
            IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options,
            IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        }
    }
    ```
13. Go to *App_Start* folder → Open *Startup.Auth.cs* and add the following code to the `ConfigureAuth` method:

    ```
    ConfigureAuthapp.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
    ```

Now the project is ready to take advantage of the new `ApplicationRole`.

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you so much. At the moment I just inherited the IdentityRole with a discriminator field in my table. Seems to work fine as well? What is the difference between this method and mine?

Comment: You're welcome, The main difference is in step 11 (and 4).

Comment: @El7or You're welcome, thanks for the feedback. In case you are customizing identity user as well, you may want to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40579369/3110834).

Comment: @Örvar Great! Thanks for the feedback :)