# ASP.NET MVC Adding Required Annotation to extended IdentityRole

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have just extended my AspNetRoles table like this:

```
public class AspApplicationRoles : IdentityRole
{
    public AspApplicationRoles() : base() { }
    public AspApplicationRoles(String Name) : base(Name) { }
    [Required]
    public String ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public AspNetApplications Application { get; set; }
}
```

How do I make the Name property Required? Is it possible? So far I can only add it to my ApplicationId. Also, how do I add a new Role? So far if I use the RoleManager to add it, it only asks for the name.

Comment: Yes. But it says I can't add it to declaration types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option you can create a new view model for role creation. This is similar to what has been done for users in the default MVC project template when you enable individual users authentication. If you take a look at `AccountViewModels.cs`, you see a couple of view models.

For example, you can create the following class:

```
public class ApplicationRoleCreateModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Application Id")]
    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
}
```

Supposing you have created `ApplicationRole` class including custom properties as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52029846/3110834), then can create the following role controller class:

```
[Authorize]
public class RoleController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;

    public RoleController() { }

    public RoleController(ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
    {
        RoleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleManager ?? 
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }
        private set { _roleManager = value; }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = RoleManager.Roles.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(ApplicationRoleCreateModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationRole()
            {
                Name = model.Name,
                ApplicationId = model.ApplicationId
            });
            if (result.Succeeded)
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            else
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It slipped my mind that I needed a ViewModel. Was already using them before. Thank you again!

Comment: Oh Okay. Will do that then. I also have a new question. Would you be able to take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039445/the-object-cannot-be-deleted-because-it-was-not-found-in-the-objectstatemanager